# Computer doesnt charge and harddrive fail after spilling fluids

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure, battery, battery-life

I spilled tea under my laptop (Dell 7520 15R) yesterday, water got on my rams, hard drive and battery. Computer shut down immediately. I cleaned everything, assembled it and it works fine, except that battery is not charging. I'll try to explain whats happening:

- Indicating led of connected power is not working when I connect AC power adapter
- If I disconnect power adapter, laptop runs on battery
- If I connect power adapter, it says that battery is fully charged and it does not charge battery, but battery is always on the same level and charger supplies power directly to pc.

Furthermore, I ran hard drive tests and got these errors:

- SMART Short Self test FAIL
- Linear read test FAIL

How long my hard drive will work? (Im backuping it right now). Is it charger, battery or battery connector in pc problem that my battery is not charging? Maybe motherboard? Please give me some advice how to know what doesnt work or how to fix it..

I hope I asked in right forum

Comment: How bad is it...You are failing basic read tests.  You also have 3,000 bad sectors.  There isn't anything you can do about that.  You need to replace the HDD.  We cannot predict how long it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Spilling any form of liquid over electical devices is never good. I guess I don't have to tell you that. The problem is that liquid will create electical connections between points that are not supposed to be connected. As a result, circuits short out which can lead to chips blowing up.¹

Other electical items such as condensators can also stop working. A rule of thumb here is: The more advanced electical innerworkings the device has, the worse damage can occur during a spill.

Given that your laptop still works can be called a miracle, but I would use this time to get all tha backups you need and then buy a replacement laptop.

You never know what else was hit by the water spill, and your laptop is definitely out of balance.

*¹) Side note: By blowing up, I do not literally mean blowing up, but they'll burn out, causing some smoke and a burning smell.*

Comment: It's not the 1950's anymore. Every calls them "capacitors" now!